# is.na() behaves differently than is.numeric() - where's the consistency?

Tags: r

Let's create the data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(VarA = c(1, NA, 5), VarB = c(NA, 2, 7))

  VarA VarB
1    1   NA
2   NA    2
3    5    7
```

If I run a simple NA query it shows me the locations of each NA.

```
is.na(df)

      VarA  VarB
[1,] FALSE  TRUE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE
```

Why doesn't `is.numeric` return the same type of data frame? It only outputs a single "FALSE".

```
is.numeric(df)

[1] FALSE
```

Is there a good explanation of data types, classes, etc. somewhere? I read about these things often but don't have a solid feel for them. I don't get the difference between a matrix and data frame, or num vs dbl. It's easy to conflate these things.

I did the Cyclismo "basic data types" tutorial but would like to dig a little deeper.

Comment: this section of Advanced R might help (http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html). Note that NA can be specified as real, integer, etc. Also is.na has a data.frame method which will check each element individually. is.numeric will check the class of the entire object (which is a data.frame not numeric). The NA's in your df are actually numeric NAs because of the way you set of the df...so even checking each element with is.numeric will return true...i.e. is.numeric(df[2,1]). So using is.na is probably better if you are searching for NAs

Comment: Advanced R is just what I needed. I also found DataCamp "Introduction to R" which is quite helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### First - documentation

Let's turn to the documentation. From `?is.na`:

> The generic function `is.na` indicates which elements are missing.

So `is.na` is made to tell you which individual elements within an object are missing.

From `?is.numeric`:

> `is.numeric` is a more general test of an object being interpretable as numbers.

So `is.numeric` tells you whether an object is numeric (not whether individual elements within the object are numeric).

These are behaving exactly as documented - `is.na(df)` tells you which elements of the data frame are missing. `is.numeric(df)` tells you what `df` is not `numeric` (in fact, it is a `data.frame`).

### Is it inconsistent?

I can see how this seems inconsistent. There are just a few `is.*` functions that work element-wise. `is.na`, `is.finite`, `is.nan` are the only ones I can think of. All the other `is.*` functions work on the whole object. These function are essentially stand-ins for equality testing with `==` when the equality testing wouldn't work (more on this below). But once you understand the data structures a little more, they don't seem inconsistent, because they really wouldn't make sense the other way.

#### `is.numeric` makes sense the way it is

It would not make sense for `is.numeric` to be applied element-wise. A vector is either numeric or not in its entirety - whether or not it has missing values. If you wanted to apply the `is.numeric` function to each column of your data frame, you could do

```
sapply(df, is.numeric)
```

Which will tell you that both columns are `numeric`. You *could* make an argument that the default behavior when `is.numeric()` is given a data frame should be to apply it to every column, but it's possible someone want to make sure that something is a `numeric` vector, not a `data.frame` (or anything else), and having, say, a one-column `data.frame` say `TRUE` to `is.numeric()` could cause confusion and errors.

#### `is.na` makes sense the way it is

Conversely, it wouldn't make sense for `is.na` to *not* be applied element-wise. `NA` is a stand-in for a single value, not a complicated object like a `data.frame`. It wouldn't really make sense to have a "missing" data frame - you could have a missing value but there's nothing to tell you that it's a data frame. However a `data.frame` (or a vector, or a matrix...) can *contain* missing values, and `is.na` will tell you exactly where they are.

This is pretty much identical to how equality (or other comparisons) work. You could also check for 1s in your data frame with `df == 1`, or for values less than 5 with `df < 5`. `is.na()` is the recommended way to check for missing values - `anything == NA` returns `NA`, so `df == NA` doesn't work for that. `is.na(df)` is the right way to do this.

To accomplish this, `is.na` actually has many methods. You can seem them with `methods("is.na")`. In my current R session, I see

```
methods("is.na")
 [1] is.na,abIndex-method       is.na,denseMatrix-method   is.na,indMatrix-method    
 [4] is.na,nsparseMatrix-method is.na,nsparseVector-method is.na,sparseMatrix-method 
 [7] is.na,sparseVector-method  is.na.coxph.penalty*       is.na.data.frame          
[10] is.na.data.table*          is.na.integer64*           is.na.numeric_version     
[13] is.na.POSIXlt              is.na.raster*              is.na.ratetable*          
[16] is.na.Surv*
```

This shows me that all these different types of objects support a `is.na()` call to nicely tell me where missing values are inside of them. And if I call it on another object class, then `is.na.default` will try to handle it.

### Secondary questions

> I don't get the difference between a matrix and data frame, or num vs dbl. It's easy to conflate these things.

`num` vs `dbl` is not relevant to R. I'm shocked that anything directed at R beginners would mention doubles - it shouldn't. If you look at the help at `?double` it includes.

> It is identical to `numeric`.
>
> ... `as.double` is a generic function. It is identical to `as.numeric`.

For R purposes, forget the term `double` and just use `numeric`.

---

> I don't get the difference between a matrix and data frame

Both are rectangular - rows and columns. A `matrix` can only have one data type/class inside it - the whole matrix is `numeric`, or `character`, or `integer`, etc, with no mixing. A `data.frame` can have different class for each of its columns, the first column can be numeric, the second character, the third factor, etc.

Matrices are simpler and more efficient, very suitable for linear algebra operations. Data frames are much more common because it is common to have data of mixed types.

Comment: this is better than mine.

Answer (score 4):

Primarily because the test in `is.numeric()` applies to the whole object (so returns a single value that says whether the entire object is numeric), while `is.na()` applies to individual elements of the object.

The next, subtler question (which you haven't asked yet but might ask next) is: why doesn't `is.numeric()` return TRUE, since all the elements of the data frame are numeric? It's because data frames are internally represented as lists, and could contain elements of different types (`is.numeric(as.matrix(df))` does return TRUE).

Answer (score 0):

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
$ VarA: num  1 NA 5
$ VarB: num  NA 2 7
```

The thing to consider is this, `is.na` is testing each value that appears in a vector... whereas `is.numeric` is checking the class of the object itself. It's apples-to-oranges in a sense. Think of it like this,

*Is this object Not Available(NA)? Since it exists, check each object contained in the tested vectors. Is this object a number? Nope.. it's a data.frame*